# How can I merge a finite number of infinite lists in Haskell?

Tags: list, haskell, functional-programming

For an assignment I need to write some Haskell code which has as input a finite list consisting of infinite lists of integers, each list monotonically increasing.

Now, I need to merge these into one single list which orders the integers. Also, some integers may appear in multiple lists: in the output list, each integer may only appear once in the list.

So if the input is for example [ [1, 2, 6, 10, 28, 40, ...] [3, 4, 10, 28, 100, ...] , [any number of lists] ] then the output should be [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 10, 28, 40, 100, ...]

I am a little stuck here. I do not know how to use `foldr` effectively to merge the lists. I think I should compare the heads of each list and make a new list out of that one.

Comment: Sorting infinite lists is not usually very easy.  If I had the input `[[1, 3, 4, 5, 6, ...], [1, 3, 5, 7, ..]]`, and I start sorting them to get `[1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, ...]`, how am I to know that a 2 doesn't appear somewhere in those two input lists?

Comment: This isn't possible unless you know the lists are monotonically increasing, which I'm guessing is stated in the assignment.  Can you confirm and show us what you have tried?  People here are usually more helpful if you do more than say "show me how".

Comment: I suspect from the sample data that each input list is already sorted, and a merge is all that's required.

Comment: Or, instead, are you wanting to merge these lists, taking the lowest head from each as you move down the list?  Can you assume that once you've reached 40, you won't ever see 39 in any of the other lists?

Comment: You don't need to *sort* these lists, you need to *merge* them. They must be already sorted. You cannot sort an infinite list.

Comment: I've stated that wrong indeed. The lists are monotonically increasing. So a merge is what's required indeed.

Comment: Have you thought about how you might merge two lists?

Answer (score 7):

You can simplify the problem a bit by thinking about merging two infinite sorted lists, and then try to generalize. The skeleton of that merge will look something like this:

```
mergeSorted :: Ord a => [a] -> [a] -> [a]
mergeSorted [] ys = ys
mergeSorted xs [] = xs
mergeSorted (x:xs) (y:ys) = ???
```

You'll have to compare x and y, and do something sensible, probably involving a recursive call to mergeSorted: this doesn't look too bad, right?

Now, let's imagine that mergeSorted works, and you can turn two infinite sorted lists into one infinite sorted list. How do you turn N infinite sorted lists into a single sorted list? Why, that's a simple fold! Just merge two lists together, then merge a third with that one, and a fourth with that one, and so on.

```
mergeAll :: Ord a => [[a]] -> [a]
mergeAll xss = foldr ???
```

Comment: I'll bite, I fail to see how you'll resolve with a foldr the merge for `[[1],[7], [3], [2]]`

Comment: @mhitza (**note to OP**, you may consider this a **spoiler**): Easy. `mergeAll = foldr mergeSorted []; mergeAll [[1],[7], [3], [2]]` then evaluates to `[1,2,3,7]`, as expected.

Comment: @Will Ness, in that case, the most succinct answer would be to use unionAll from Data.List.Ordered, which does exactly what the OP is looking for. Ganesh, don't look at the source for unionAll, unless you don't mind full spoilers. In general, Data.List.Ordered includes functions that operate on ordered lists.

Comment: @fgv I wanted it done with standard HOFs (fold/unfold/until), as the OP mentioned "using foldr".

Comment: mergeAll, not unionAll, solves the problem posted here. Edit: whoa wait, I missed a sentence in the question this whole time! I guess it is union, not merge. Fortunately my skeleton function is still fine.

Answer (score 1):

We can merge any pair of *infinite* monotonically increasing lists (such as you have) by repeatedly pulling a minimal element out of either one of the lists, by `unfoldr pull` (`unfoldr` is in `Data.List`), with

```
pull (x:xs,y:ys) | x<y = Just (x, (xs,y:ys))
                 | x>y = Just (y, (x:xs,ys))
                 | x==y = Just (x, (xs, ys))  -- pull same from both (NB!)
```

and we can process any finite list by pairs, halving its length:

```
pairs f (x:y:t)  = f (x,y) : pairs f t
pairs _ t        = t
```

To repeat a step until a condition is met, is the job of `until`:

```
uniquelyMerge xs = ... (until (...) (pairs (unfoldr pull)) xs)
.....
```

Don't forget to handle the empty list case.